# Trying to Compile AOSParadox bacon_marshmallow, failing to build after a minute

Tags: android, command-prompt, android-source

System is Ubuntu 15.04. Currently I'm trying to compile AOSParadox  for OnePlus One and it's failing to compile time and time again for different reasons. Before it failed after 39 minutes and then an hour and 30 minutes but now I tweaked some things after searching up the errors I was getting (forgot to record them and now forgotten) and it's failing after 1 minute and 49 seconds roughly. Here's a pastebin of what's going on. I'm using the instructions as written here. https://github.com/AOSParadox/local_aosparadox

http://pastebin.com/pUCWjjw8

Sorry if I'm missing information here but I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to building ROMs and Linux.

Comment: That's often happens with AOSP builds - they can fail when build environment changes. You can try to build with Ubuntu 14, it may be closer to that used by ROM maintainers. And I recommend to write down changes you do in AOSP build to make it working. `repo status` may help you there. It would be good if you specify the commands you used to build, do you build for full_bacon? From your logs I can't say what the problem is. The only thing I noticed that you use not good folder name /home/"usrname" - quotes usually are not used in folder names. Not sure if it causes the problem.

Comment: I did . build/envsetup.sh && lunch full_yourdevice-userdebug and then make -j8 otapackage. The "usrname" was just to obscure my name. No quotes in the actual thing. I just set up according to CM instructions and successfully built the lollipop branch of AOSParadox so I'm going to try the marshmallow branch soon.

Comment: I also asked the ROM maintainers and they said that they compiled under 15.04.